# Is this how ailerons are actuated?

Tags: aircraft-design, ailerons

I was wondering how ailerons work on fighter jets. I came across this after hours of research.

[image: Source: https://forum.flitetest.com/index.php?threads/airplanes-in-real-life.63837/#lg=post-580884&slide=0]

Is that how fighter jet ailerons work? Is their a better picture or image that would be better. If there is please post it to help me understand. I've researched for so long on this subject with no avail except this picture that helped me understand it. Thank so much!

Comment: Can you tell what you don't understand? That might help to find something that helps with the points you didn't understand yet.

Comment: I don't understand how the linear actuator causes the aileron to move. I found this picture but I know its a bit too simple and its not the full process. Im looking for a picture that would explain how this works.

Comment: I edited the title to be more precise. As I understand, you are interesting in how they are put in movement, not the other aspects of how it works (e.g. aerodynamics). Feel free to edit again if I misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: Ok thank you. Im sorry my titles are not clear enough. Im new on the aviation stack exchange

Comment: Your question posts two different pictures of different mechanisms and then says "Is that how fighter jet ailerons work?".   I think the question could be improved to be more clear as to what you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

In the lower picture that accompanies the graphic in your link, focus on the elongated figure eight shaped piece.  The lower portion is attached to a piston extending from the actuator, and is free to pivot about the attaching point.

The upper portion of this link is fixed to the aileron and the entire part acts as a lever arm.  So, when the dark gray piston of the actuator moves left and right, the figure eight lever pivots clockwise or counter clockwise centered on the middle of the upper circle.  Since this part of the link is attached to the aileron, it also moves.

The graphic isn’t great, but try to visualize which parts move from my description and let me know if you are still confused.

You typically won't see the actual control horn on full sized aircraft because it will either be covered be a fairing to streamline it, or it will be contained within the thickness of the wing structure.

For example, in small RC models it is common to have an external horn like this:

[image]

However, you will generally NOT see a large external actuator like this on a full sized plane:

[image]

There simply isn't a need for such a large mechanism on most airplanes, and it would come with a large drag penalty.  If extra leverage is needed and the mechanism protrudes beyond the thickness of the wing it will be covered by a fairing like this:

[image]

Instead, most designers will try to keep actuators contained within the wing, as in the photos below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi im still confused about why you dont see the control horn on the aielron on planes. Sorry I replied to this comment very late

Comment: @Luke Justin, the control horn is internal, just like in the diagrams you included with the question.  Full sized aircraft do not have this part on the outside like RC planes you may have seen.

Comment: The figure 8 is the horn...

Comment: I know but how do they cover it up on the aircraft? Is the fairing attached to a hinge on the control horn?

Comment: It's just contained within the thickness of the wing structure, or there may be a bump to cover it. I don't know how to explain it beyond that. Your diagram is a generic example, aircraft differ somewhat. My best recommendation would be to go look at a real airplane. I don't think it needs to have hydraulic controls to make the point, find a local flight school or airplane museum and ask there.

Comment: @Luke Justin, see additional photos in my answer and let me know it that helps clear anything up.

Comment: Thanks the pictures helped so much. However, how do they contatin the mechniasm in the wing. Is their a picture of the whole mechnisms in the wing not just close up?

Comment: The photos are General Aviation aircraft and homebuilts, not fighters as you are asking about.  So, they have manually actuated controls using pushrods and cables.  But, try to visualize a hydraulic cylinder in there instead of a pushrod and I think you will get the picture.  I just found these by Googling keywords like "aileron actuator" etc.  Dig a little, use your imagination...  it is a pretty simple lever arrangement, I don't think you will get a better answer than what I already have given you.

Comment: Sorry if Im annyoing by keep asking you questions but this aileron actuator question is one of those I just cant go to sleep not fully understanding it. I understand all the components  involved. Ive researched diagrams of the f22&35 and I can even see the actuaors. I just dont really understand how it is covered up by the bulge/fairing yes still works. How is it possible for the fairing to be connected to the wing and the aileron even though they both move? Also in plane diagrams it seems the actuator is in the middle of the aileron not the side. That confused me (research f22 cutway diagram)

Comment: I'm just not sure what your hang up in understanding is.  It isn't an F-22 or F-35, but look at the third photo in my answer.  Half the fairing is attached to the wing, and half to the aileron.  One of these pieces can slide inside the other when it moves.  This was described by someone on your other post who compared it to the way an elbow joint on a suit of armor moves.  And in your other post, you can clearly see this same type of seam on the photo you posted of the F-22.  There are two separate parts that are rigged to work together.

Comment: I'm just not sure what more I can say.  If words and photos are not enough I would recommend you find a local mentor who can help demonstrate some of these mechanical concepts to you.

Comment: I am young and really want to be an aerospace engineer...but have bassicly no mentorhsip and nothing to guide me. I really dont have any kind of mentor around. (The thing I am still consufed about the aielron is like a video of it moving from the underside of the plane so I can see how the fairing moves and stuff. Also was the third and fourth picture you added to the answer from a video?)

Comment: I wish I could help you more Luke, I have just run out of ideas.  I just pulled the photos from Google images.  Do you live anywhere near Seattle by chance?

Comment: Any there any nearby flight schools?  Does your school have a STEM program?  Are there any Civil Air Patrol squadrons in your area?  These are all good ways to find a mentor who can guide you.

Comment: I accutly was going to join a Civil Air Patorl sqaudron nearby but because of covid I cant. I thought they only teach you how to fly. The teach you also about engineering?

Comment: Not straight engineering per se, but you can learn a lot about airplanes.  Squadrons can vary somewhat depending on members, and their expertise and interests.  I would encourage you to look into it when you have a chance.  Check out a couple squadrons if there is a choice.  Good luck!

Comment: Does your school have a robotics program?  Also, (not sure your age...) consider something like an Erector set.  I picked up a lot of practical knowledge and insight of basic mechanical functions playing around with mine as a kid.

Comment: My school isnt really big about engineering or that. I am in the robotics club but its Lego Mindstorm which is not that high level. If I do to college Im defiantly going to major in Aerospace Engineering and try to get an internship. Ive been looking for ways to enhance my knoweldge about the subject. I'm going to get into Civil Air patrol (when the pandemic ends) and I'm looking into a lot of books. Also I think there is a slight chance ill be allowed flight lessons soon. I just fear I wont picked be picked for a job/interneship because of me not knowing a lot about engineering.